# move rows into new columns based on keywords to split

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to convert the csv [Original csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofSeE.jpg)

using special keyword 'read' as a keyword to split the rows and move the rows into new columns [converted csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2pHn.jpg). plz refer to the images attached.
anyone has idea how to achieve using python pandas?

example(original csv):
dfA
dfB
dfC

converted csv:
dfA dfB dfC

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correct, you would like to transpose your dataframe, here is how you can do it

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["dfA", "dfB", "dfC"]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.values).T
```

Comment: thanks i think transpose will do, based on the transpose idea, you have idea how to identify the if a keyword is in a row to separate the dataframe into dfA dfB dfC....... coz the original csv is composed of these parts.